# How to resize <img> in <div> with float:left?

Tags: html, css, dynamic, height, width

I've got problem, how to automatic resize **height** of  in .

***[Here](http://crazyones.tk/newshow1.html)*** I'am trying to make pure css slideshow, and its works, but when I scale browser window **width** changes and **height** - doesn't. Why? and how to fix this?

more of all I'll try to use different hack/advices and use a lot of them ***[here](http://crazyones.tk/newshow.html)***, but it didnt work. When I change **width manualy(in css), height changes**.

How to change height dynamic in this examples?

*p.s. sorry for my bad english...I hope you understand me...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i have check to this

if i **remove this**

```
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**than your slider is ok** ...

Comment: thnx, you for your answer, but your answer didnt solve the problem with height... p.s. I tried *{...} for box-scale, and hope it scale height, but it didnt worked...